# Found Wildcard AlphaSSL Cert Private Key of large Webhoster - what now?

Tags: certificate-authority

I just stumbled upon the wildcard ssl certificate private key protecting the control panels of my (rather large) webhoster - it was world readable inside a common directory accessible by all tenants on the server.

The webhoster ignores my requests to revoke / replace the certificate / making this file not world-readable.

The certificate was issued by AlphaSSL.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Send the a signed message to the issuer of the certificate. They will be forced to revoke it when you prove that you have the private key.

This can be done with the following command:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign keyfile -out signature text-file-to-sign.txt
```

Send the `signature` and `text-file-to-sign.txt` to the issuer. Ask them to verify with

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public-keyfile -signature signature text-file-to-sign.txt
```

In this way you prove that you have the private key, without revealing the content of the private key. Any issuer that adheres to the rules should revoke the key when they learn that a third party has access to it.

Another way would be to send the key itself in e-mail to the issuer. This should only be done if you can send encrypted e-mail to the issuer, to avoid more compromise of security than needed.